# GSL eigenvalues of complex non hermitian matrix

Tags: c, matrix, gsl, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I'd like to compute eigenvalues/eigenvectors of a **non hermitian complex** matrix with GSL. I've been reading the doc and I didn't find any clue for this case, only real non-symm or hermitian matrices. It doesn't say neither that it's impossible. The code I've used so far is the following, of course output is wrong as the function is not designed for that:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                   
#include <complex.h>                                                                                                 
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>                                                                                            
#include <gsl/gsl_eigen.h>                                                                                           
                                                                                                                     
int                                                                                                                  
main (void)                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                     
  double data[] = { -1, 1, 1,0, -1.0,0, 1.0,0,                                                                       
    -8.0,0, 4.0,0, -2.0,0, 1.0,0,                                                                                    
    27.0,0, 9.0,0, 3.0,0, 1.0,0,                                                                                     
    64.0,0, 16.0,0, 4.0,0, 1.0,0 };                                                                                  
                                                                                                                     
  gsl_matrix_complex_view m                                                                                          
    = gsl_matrix_complex_view_array (data, 4, 4);                                                                    
                                                                                                                     
  gsl_vector_complex *eval = gsl_vector_complex_alloc (4);                                                           
  gsl_matrix_complex *evec = gsl_matrix_complex_alloc (4, 4);                                                        
                                                                                                                     
  gsl_eigen_nonsymmv_workspace * w =                                                                                 
    gsl_eigen_nonsymmv_alloc (4);                                                                                    
                                                                                                                     
  gsl_eigen_nonsymmv (&m.matrix, eval, evec, w);                                                                     
                                                                                                                     
  gsl_eigen_nonsymmv_free (w);                                                                                       
                                                                                                                     
  gsl_eigen_nonsymmv_sort (eval, evec,                                                                               
                           GSL_EIGEN_SORT_ABS_DESC);                                                                 
                                                                                                                     
  {                                                                                                                  
    int i, j;                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                     
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)                                                                                          
      {                                                                                                              
        gsl_complex eval_i                                                                                           
           = gsl_vector_complex_get (eval, i);                                                                       
        gsl_vector_complex_view evec_i                                                                               
           = gsl_matrix_complex_column (evec, i);                                                                    
                                                                                                                     
        printf ("eigenvalue = %g + %gi\n",                                                                           
                GSL_REAL(eval_i), GSL_IMAG(eval_i));                                                                 
        printf ("eigenvector = \n");                                                                                 
        for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)                                                                                      
          {                                                                                                          
            gsl_complex z =                                                                                          
              gsl_vector_complex_get(&evec_i.vector, j);                                                             
            //printf("%g + %gi\n", GSL_REAL(z), GSL_IMAG(z));                                                        
          }                                                                                                          
      }                                                                                                              
  }                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                     
  gsl_vector_complex_free(eval);                                                                                     
  gsl_matrix_complex_free(evec);                                                                                     
                                                                                                                     
  return 0;                                                                                                          
}
```

Thank you and sorry if I'm missing something obvious..

EDIT: here is the output of compilation and running:

```
eigen.c: In function ‘main’:
eigen.c:24:23: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘gsl_eigen_nonsymmv’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   24 |   gsl_eigen_nonsymmv (&m.matrix, eval, evec, w);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~
      |                       |
      |                       gsl_matrix_complex *
In file included from eigen.c:4:
/usr/include/gsl/gsl_eigen.h:144:38: note: expected ‘gsl_matrix *’ but argument is of type ‘gsl_matrix_complex *’
  144 | int gsl_eigen_nonsymmv (gsl_matrix * A, gsl_vector_complex * eval,
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
eigen.c:46:25: warning: unused variable ‘z’ [-Wunused-variable]
   46 |             gsl_complex z =
      |                         ^
eigenvalue = 1.78447 + 1.96117i
eigenvector = 
eigenvalue = 1.78447 + -1.96117i
eigenvector = 
eigenvalue = -0.568946 + 0i
eigenvector = 
eigenvalue = -3.36586e-18 + 0i
eigenvector =
```

Comment: Other than an incorrect algorithm, is there anything wrong with the C code?  i.e. does it compile and run without issue?

Comment: it runs and compile but complains about giving to the function a complex matrix instead of a real one.

Comment: Is the _complaint_ a run-time message?  If so, post its exact content.

Comment: It may be that you will need to write your own _non-hermitian complex_ algorithm, and if so the [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange might be a good place to ask about that.

Comment: I edited the message with output of compilation and running, well I'm quite surprised it doesn't already exist it is something quite basic and GSL is intended for scientific computation where you find a lot of non-hermitian complex matrix ...

Comment: The error message  (stating the obvious) points directly to the problem...  The function prtotype: [int gsl_eigen_nonsymmv(gsl_matrix *A, gsl_vector_complex *eval, gsl_matrix_complex *evec, gsl_eigen_nonsymmv_workspace *w)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/eigen.html) calls for the first argument to be of type: `gsl_matrix`, but you have populated it with an argument of type: `gsl_matrix_complex_view`.  It appears the second argument  will accommodate the complex matrix.

Comment: Yes but others argument are intended to be the answers, the first argument is the matrix I want to diagonalize. I know this function doesn't accept complex matrix, what I'm looking for is a workaround to make this thing works, as this problem is quite common I expect something to exist.

Comment: posting a question in mathematics stack exchange may lead to something useful.  (Link in my 3rd comment.)

Comment: I just spent a few minutes looking at the description and usage of the [gsl_matrix](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/vectors.html#c.gsl_matrix) type.  It does a accommodate complex content.  Read the entire section, particularly how to create one dynamically.  I think you might be able to use what you find.

Comment: I have no issue putting complex content in the matrix. My issue is how to get the **eigenvalues** of this matrix.

Comment: _"This chapter describes functions for computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrices. There are routines for real symmetric, real nonsymmetric, complex hermitian"_  [Did you already see this?](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/eigen.html)

Comment: Yes I've seen that! This is precisely the question: where can I find a function to get the eigenvalues if the matrix is non real or non hermitian ? I've read your comment about mathexchange but I don't want to write such a function myself, this would require a lot of time and the result would probably be very lame.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not limit to C, you can also use the eigen library of C++ [https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Contributing_to_Eigen]